# Why my controller not getting data from ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm new to this, I'm trying to get the data from an ajax query

This Is My Ajax

```
$('#insertfile').on('click',function() {
    console.log('a');
    var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
    var name = document.getElementById('names').value;
    if( $('#room-status-no').prop('checked') ) {
        console.log("status: 1");
        var status = 1;
    } else {
        var status = 0;
        console.log("status: 0");
    }
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    let form = new FormData();
    console.log(file);
    form.append('file', file);
    form.append('name', name);
    form.append('status', status);
    form.append('id', id);
    form.append('_method', 'PATCH');
    form.append('action', 'update_file');
    console.log(id, name, status);
  $.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    url: "{{ route('this is my route.update', 'update_file') }}",
    type: "PATCH",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType : false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: form,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('body').append('<div id="spinnerLoading"><div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-double-bounce"><div class="sk-double-bounce1"></div><div class="sk-double-bounce2"></div></div></div>');
    },
```

This is my Controller

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $action = $request->action;
    dd($request->all());
    if($action == 'update_text'){
        return $this->updatetextControl($request);
    } else if($action == 'update_file') {
        return  $this->updateFileControl($request);
}
```

I'm trying to pass the form data to my laravel controller using `dd($request->all());`
I was unable to get any data in my controller, I'm not sure if my URL route is the problem or I cant have multiple update functions others thing in one controller, does anyone know a solution? it will be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did you check whether the request contains that data? Check your browser's network console for this

Comment: i have when i check my browser network it show the console log data, but when i check the laravel request data it was just an empty array "[ ]"

Comment: can you edit your question to add you controller code